# How to adapt the position of a UIButton to a background image for all iPhone sizes?

Tags: swift, xcode

I just begin swift and I'm facing a simple problem:
I can't adapt a `UIButton` to an image in my storyboard for all iPhone sizes. I work with a storyboard with the size of an iPhone 6s Plus because I have one. When I run my test, all it's OK but when I run my test with iPhone 5 simulator, nothing is good.
This image shows the button is in the good place on iPhone 6 plus but no to other sizes.
I tried so many different constraints but nothing seem to work.

**In summary:** How can I set constraints to position a button at the circle in the background image (as shown in the [linked drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYcKi.png)), regardless of phone size?

[image: Button Not Aligned With Circle]

Comment: I think you're asking, Matt, **how to set constraints to position your button at the circle in the background, as shown in the linked drawing, regardless of phone size**. If this is correct, please edit your question to say that, so the moderators will take your question off hold. (I can edit it, if you'd like, but I want to make sure I didn't misunderstand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your constraints to a percentage.

- Control-drag from your button to your view.
- Shift-click to select Horizontal Spacing and Vertical Spacing.
- Click Add Constraints.
  Now, you should have 2 constraints for the button, relative to the superview.
- In the Attributes Inspector for each constraint, check to ensure the button's  X and Y are relative to the trailing edge and bottom of your superview. For example:

> First Item: Button.Center X
>   Relation: Equal
>   Second Item: Superview.Trailing
>
> First Item: Button.Center Y
>   Relation: Equal
>   Second Item: Superview.Bottom

- In each constraint, set the constant value to zero.
- Then, set the multiplier value to a percentage or fraction.

For example, if you want the button to be at the halfway point, regardless of device size, enter a multiplier of 50% (or 1/2 or .5 if it won't take the percent value - sometimes it won't accept one version of a value, but it will accept another expression of the same thing).

The percentage is multiplied by the superview's values. The superview's trailing edge is the max X value, and the superview's bottom edge is the max Y value.

Your button appears to be around a third of the way down the view, and about a quarter of the view on the left. So you might try setting the Button.Center X multiplier to 25% or 1/4 or .25, and the Y multiplier to 33% or 1/3 or .33

Note also that under a constraint's Second Item dropdown, you can select whether the value is relative to the margin. If that is not selected, the multiplier uses the full width or height of the superview. Selecting Relative to margin uses the width of the superview minus any trailing or bottom margin. That could throw off your percentages. I recommend leaving Relative to margin unselected when playing with your values.

Here are images for the end constraint values:
[image: Button.Center X Equal PNG.Trailing, Multiplier 26%]
[image: Button.Center Y Equal PNG.Bottom, Multiplier 46%]

Note that the button doesn't seem to be centered until you look at the preview. Running the simulators for the different sized phones gave me the same results as shown in the preview: button correctly centered in the circle.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! 
i tried this. now here's my result: 
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvPAYA1fjd14gZhHIxWcsRmISol2Rw
maybe i made mistake?

Comment: The Second Item says "iPhone 6 Plus.Leading", @Matt Jacquet. Try changing that to "iPhone 6 Plus.Trailing".

Comment: That one looks right, @MattJacquet. I'm not sure why it's not spacing more consistently. Is "Relative to margin" unchecked under the Second Item dropdown?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the background image you're using, so I can play with it a bit?

Comment: it seem impossible. i asked this so many times to severals forums.. and nothing. 
Thanks a lot Leanne for your time :-)

Comment: Nope - not impossible! I tried with the PNG you provided. You see the value in your constraints, the Constant is set to 0; however, the wC hR box still has a value in it. Change that value to 0, then try the percents again. I was able to center it for all 3 phone sizes with Multipliers set to 46% for Y and 26% for X. Will add images to my solution.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution, @MattJacquet, if you would!

Comment: i think i did it but i'm not sure .. :-)